# is there a shortcut for code folding on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a way to close/open foldable blocks of code using the Keyboard. I found some shortcuts in old answers but none of them seem to work on the version of Eclipse that I use (2020-09).

Comment: Please edit your question to specify a particular version of Eclipse, since in two years your version will no longer be "the newest version".

Comment: I also used that Eclipse feature for a while. Then I realized that whenever I felt the need to use it, the file simply had too many lines. For me, that is a file that I have to work on a lot and that has more than 200 lines. So if your file has more than 200 lines, and you need to work in it often, you probably implemented something in a not-so-good manner. The only time big source code files may exist is when you have to include a lot of datasets / enum cases / step-by-step-sequences. But then you should hardly ever work in that file. Use delegation to helper classes, or inheritance or enums

Comment: Most common code-smell with big files is copy/past code duplication with minor changes, that actually should be solved by parametrization or different object component models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cmd (on macOS) or Alt (on Windows) and the subtract and divide on numeric keypads. If you don't have an external keypad then you can remap it yourself by going to preferences, and then keys, and you can enter your own.

If you want to expand/collapse all of them, you can hold shift down as well.